# .ICEauthority is missing

Tags: logging

Can I create a new file .ICEauthirity or download it from anywhere? 
Problem is when I logging in.There is this error message "Can't update .ICEauthority home/user/.ICEauthority".But there is no such file with Ctrl+H or without it.So I can't debug this and looking for solution of this trouble. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it let you log in at all?